# Filter some unique Data with LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i am very new with C# and MVC.

My Problem:

I have a list OF IDs

```
int[] mylist = {10, 23}
```

I try to query some data from DB

```
var result = db.tableName.Where(o => mylist.Any(y => y == o.item_ID && o.readed)).ToList();
```

This is what I get with the query:

```
item_ID Product_ID readed
277     1232       1
277     1233       1
277     1235       1
280     1235       1
```

What I need is:

```
item_ID Product_ID readed
277     1235       1
280     1235       1
```

If I change "any" to "all" i don't get any results, but I have definitely one item where the condition fits.

I think its more like make a query with id 277, then a query with 280 and then merge the list and return only where where "Product_ID" match.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend checking what query actually runs against the database, with either of the answers below. For example, you can use SQL Server Profiler if your DB is SQL Server.

Comment: Please could you post a http://sscce.org/ along with the EXPECTED results. Try posting on https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Does your `myList` includes in 272 and 280?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev yes, as I said, I get the correct list, but its more like a list this items for 1 ID and a list this items for second ID. The SQL i show do the stuff correct

Comment: @Fincha I have updated my answer as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you need is this:

```
var temp = db.tableName.Where(o => mylist.Any(y => y == o.item_ID && o.readed))
                       .ToList();

// Find the Product_id which appeared more than one time
// By the way, this assumes that there is at least one product_Id whihc has appeared more than one time
var neededProductID = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Product_ID)
                          .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                          .First()
                          .Key;

// Filter the result by neededProductID 
var result = temp.Where(x => x.Product_ID == neededProductID).ToList();
```

Also, if there could be more tha one Product_ID which has apperaed more than one time, then you can consider this:

```
var neededProductID = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Product_ID)
                          .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(x => x.Key)
                          .ToList();

var result = temp.Where(x => neededProductID.Any(y => y == x.Product_ID)).ToList();
```

By the way, you don't need `All()`. It tells you if all the elements in a collection match a certain condition.

Comment: Then, please update your question with inputs and outputs sample?

Comment: I have added an image to my question, I currently use your solution, makes the most sense.

Comment: @Fincha Why you need 2 equals? COuld you please explain us? You have not explained what output you want and why?

Comment: I have added some sql, I think it makes this really clear. I need items of special kind with readed = 1

Comment: @Fincha  
Does your myList includes in 272 and 280?

Comment: @Fincha Your LINQ query is OK. But, it means that your `myList` includes all 8 ids in your result. Not only 272 and 280.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was testing with 272 but using the 277 in my test case!

Comment: I think I was to early to celebrate... I have updated my question, have you any idea?

Comment: @Fincha Do you need maximum one?

Comment: I added an explaination to the questtion

Comment: @Fincha What you need is GroupBy and find the maximum one. CHeck my update.

Comment: I dont think it works this way, cos of "max" it dont have to be the max value, as I said, its more a merge maybe concat? of to lists

Comment: @Fincha Mut it be a last value? Or must be same productId?

Comment: It must be the same product_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

`var result = db.tableName.Where(o => mylist.conains(o.item_ID) 
                && o.readed).ToList();`

Comment: Can you try to compare the SQL version with what you want to achieve

Comment: can you take a look at the question now?